# Issues connecting to an IKEv2 VPN "The parameter is incorrect"

Tags: networking, windows-10, vpn

I've set up a VPN using StrongSwan software on a DigitalOcean server.
I used this guide here :https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-ikev2-vpn-server-with-strongswan-on-ubuntu-16-04#step-4-%E2%80%94-configuring-strongswan;

The server has no issues, the ufw rules, ipsec config and StrongSwan config are all followed exactly as the tutorial shows.

Whenever I click connect on Windows 10, via the control panel VPN section, it returns the message "Can't connec to VPN" "The parameter is incorrect".

The VPN is IKEv2